# Why is learning at CPU slower than at GPU

Tags: catboost

I have:
GPU : GeForce RTX 2070 8GB.
CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core Processor.
RAM : 32GB.
Driver Version: 418.43.
CUDA Version: 10.1.
On my project, gpu is also slower than cpu. But now I will use the documentation example.

```
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
import time

start_time = time.time()

train_data = [[0,3],
          [4,1],
          [8,1],
          [9,1]]
train_labels = [0,0,1,1]

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=1000, task_type = "CPU/GPU")
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, verbose = False)

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Training time on gpu: 4.838074445724487

Training time on cpu: 0.43390488624572754

Why is the training time on gpu more than on cpu?

Comment: I don't think benchmarks like this can ever be relevant. Try a benchmark with lots and lots of data and see what results you get. 4 seconds vs 0.4 seconds might be your GPU ramping up after a low-voltage period. On this page (https://catboost.ai/news/extremely-fast-learning-on-gpu-has-arrived) you can see they are talking about datasets with tens of millions of records.

Comment: You will get speedups from training on GPU if you have large datasets, starting from thousands or tens of thousands of objects. The bigger is the dataset the bigger will be the speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Be careful, no experience with catboost, so the following is from CUDA point of view**

- **data transfer** The launch of a kernel (function called by Host, e.g. CPU, executed by device, e.g. GPU) requires data to be transferred from host to device. See image below to get an idea of the transfer time on data size. By default, the memory are non-pinned (using *cudaMalloc()*). See https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~mwb7w/cuda_support/pinned_tradeoff.html to find out more. [image]
- **kernel launch overhead** Each time when the host calls a kernel, it enqueues the kernel to the working queue of the device. i.e. for each iteration, the host instantiates a kernel, and adds to the queue. Before the introduction of [CUDA graph](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-10-features-revealed/) (which also points out that the kernel launch overhead can be significant when the kernel has short execution time), the overhead of each kernel launch cannot be avoided. I don't know how *catboost* handles iterations, but given that difference between execution times, it seems not have resolved the launch overheads (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

Catboost uses some different techniques with small datasets (rows<50k or columns<10) that reduces overfitting, but takes more time. Try training with a gigantic dataset, for instance the Epsilon dataset. see github https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/505